# How to setup new local artifactory for maven?

Tags: maven, build, repository, build-automation, artifactory

I've read many questions and articles on this and tons of other sites, I still can't get this working.

I have maven configured to perform my builds, and now want to put the artifacts into a repository.  I installed artifactory in tomcat, it appears to be working.

If I execute a "mvn clean install", the messages indicate that the artifacts are being uploaded to the local maven repository instead of artifactory:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Installing C:\maven_projects\my-app\my-app\target\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to             C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\app\my-app\1.0
-SNAPSHOT\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\maven_projects\my-app\my-app\pom.xml to     C:\Users\Administrator\.m2\repository\com\mycompany\app\my-app\1.0-SNAPSHOT\my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

If I execute a "mvn deploy:deploy-file, specifying the repository,  the messages indicate the artifacts are being uploaded into artifactory, but they are not there:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DrepositoryId=libs-release-local -Durl=http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local -D
groupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

[...]

[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) @ my-app ---
Downloading: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-20130202.014428-1.jar
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-20130202.014428-1.pom
```

The POM.XML file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
                      <repository>
                              <id>central</id>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release</url>
                      <snapshots>
                              <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </snapshots>
              </repository>
              <repository>
                      <id>snapshots</id>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
                      <releases>
                              <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </releases>
              </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
              <pluginRepository>
                      <id>central</id>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
                      <snapshots>
                              <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </snapshots>
              </pluginRepository>
              <pluginRepository>
                      <id>snapshots</id>
                      <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
                      <releases>
                              <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </releases>
              </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <distributionManagement>
<repository>
        <id>sademo</id>
        <name>sademo-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>sademo</id>
        <name>sademo-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

The settings.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>sademo</id>
</server>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>sademo-releases</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>remote-repos</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/remote-repos</url>
      <id>remote-repos</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>sademo</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>sademo-snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Any ideas on how I can get the "mvn clean install" to upload the jar into artifcatory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In maven

```
mvn install
```

is intended to install the artifacts into the local repository and **NOT** into the remote repository. 
To upload the artifacts to the remote repository you need to say:

```
mvn deploy
```

The mvn deploy will use the entries from distributionManagement to upload the artifacts to the given repository.

In your examples the pom should not contain any configurations for repositories, cause you have already done it in the settings.xml file.

Apart from that it looks that your configuration is not 100% correct, cause the message:

```
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-20130202.014428-1.jar
Uploading: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/mycompany/app/my-app/1.0-SNAPSHOT/my-app-1.0-20130202.014428-1.pom
```

shows the location where the artifacts have been put into. In this case libs-release-local but the artifacts are SNAPSHOT's and not releases.

I would say to change the following:

```
<repository>
  <snapshots />
  <id>sademo-snapshots</id>
  <name>libs-snapshot</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```

into:

```
<repository>
  <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </snapshots>
  <id>sademo-snapshots</id>
  <name>libs-snapshot</name>
  <url>http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
</repository>
```